# Kalman Filter Prediction Implementation

Tags: algorithm, prediction, robotics, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement a Kalman filter in order to localize a robot.
I am confused with the prediction step (excluding process noise) x = Fx + u

If x is a state estimation vector: [xLocation, xVelocity] and F is the state transition matrix [[1 1],[0 1]], then the new xLocation would be equal to xLocation + xVelocity + the corresponding component of the motion vector u.

Why is the equation not x = x + u?  Shouldn't the predicted location of the robot be the location + motion of the robot?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/ as you don't seem to have a problem implementing this algorithm, but you have a problem understanding the algorithm.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already and be sure to take a look at [ask].

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com may also be a better place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is some confusion with respect to what the matrices actually represent.

The "control vector", *u*, might be the acceleration externally applied to the system.

In this case, I would expect the equations to look like this:

x<sub>location</sub> = x<sub>location</sub> + x<sub>velocity</sub>

x<sub>velocity</sub> = x<sub>velocity</sub> + u<sub>velocity</sub>

These two equations assume that the update is applied every 1 second (otherwise some "delta time" factors would need to be applied and included the transition matrix and the control vector).

For the situation mentioned above, the matrices and vectors are:

- The state vector (column vector with 2 entries):

  x<sub>location</sub>

  x<sub>velocity</sub>

---

- The transition matrix (2 x 2 matrix):

  1 1

  0 1

---

- The control vector (column vector with 2 entries):

  0

  u<sub>velocity</sub>

---

[This link](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/) contains nice explanations and visualizations for the Kalman Filter.